# Javascript: If() is not reliable within loop or when based on regex objects with global or sticky flags

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean-expression

During tests for [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73226628/js-dom-manipulation-generated-incremented-ids-and-other-attributes-are-wrong-fo), I experienced a strange quirk. No idea, if it is related to the other two issues, but I don't think so.

My script iterates over a list of image URLs (taken from a textarea input) and analyses each of them for defined structures to find some type of image IDs. Basically the url from the input is tested, to see if it includes some regular expression or keywords. But when I iterate over the same URL several times, the same if-statement produces various results. Sometimes the it finds the ID and sometimes it doesn't.

I better illustrate that with a small snippet:

It doesn't make a difference if I split up the if-else statements into separate if-statements. It also makes no difference if i iterate through the URLs with `for(i=0; i < urls.length; i++)` loop instead of a for-of loop.

Any ideas what's going on here?

#### js code snippets

##### DOESN'T WORK (if inside a loop inside a function):

```js
    function preprocessImgURL(url) {
        const urls = url.trim().split(/\r?\n/);
        const aRegex = /alpha\d{9,11}z/gi;
        const cRegex = /\d{6}_[a-zA-Z]{2,3}-\d{5,8}/gi;
        
        for (let urli = 0; urli < urls.length; urli++) {
            console.log('\n\nPROCESSING NEXT URL');
            
            console.log(urls[urli]);
            if(urls[urli].includes("channelB-")) {
                console.log('Row ' + urli + ' is B Domain + B URL.');
            } else if(aRegex.test(urls[urli])) {
                console.log('Row ' + urli + ' is A URL.');
            } else if(cRegex.test(urls[urli])) {
                console.log('Row ' + urli + ' is C URL.');
            } else {
        console.log('Row ' + urli + ' doesnt match any criteria. (else statement reached)');
                console.log('Row ' + urli + ' matches b criteria: ' + ( urls[urli].includes("channelB-") ));
                console.log('Row ' + urli + ' matches aRegex: ' + aRegex.test(urls[urli]));
                console.log('Row ' + urli + ' matches cRegex: ' + cRegex.test(urls[urli]));
            }
        }
    }
  
  exampleUrlString = "https://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg\nhttps://cdn.domain.de/uploads/sites/4/2022/04/alpha1234567890z.jpg?resize=1024%2C600\nhttps://www.domainy.de/wp-content/uploads/150411_AB-43827__DSC1378.jpg\nhttps://www.domainB.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/channelB-881123-maxm-20220805-696x464.jpg\nhttps://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg\nhttps://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg";
  preprocessImgURL(exampleUrlString);
```

###### expected output:

```
Row 0 is C URL.
Row 1 is A URL.
Row 2 is C URL.
Row 3 is B URL.
Row 4 is C URL.
Row 5 is C URL.
```

###### real output:

```
Row 0 is C URL.
Row 1 is A URL.
Row 2 doesnt match any criteria. (else statement reached)
Row 3 is B URL.
Row 4 doesnt match any criteria. (else statement reached) *
Row 5 doesnt match any criteria. (else statement reached)
```

- If I remove the else-statement, row 4 produces the desired output:

  ```js
      function preprocessImgURL(url) {
          const urls = url.trim().split(/\r?\n/);
          const aRegex = /alpha\d{9,11}z/gi;
          const cRegex = /\d{6}_[a-zA-Z]{2,3}-\d{5,8}/gi;
          
          for (let urli = 0; urli < urls.length; urli++) {
              console.log('\n\nPROCESSING NEXT URL');
              
              console.log(urls[urli]);
              if(urls[urli].includes("channelB-")) {
                  console.log('Row ' + urli + ' is B Domain + B URL.');
              } else if(aRegex.test(urls[urli])) {
                  console.log('Row ' + urli + ' is A URL.');
              } else if(cRegex.test(urls[urli])) {
                  console.log('Row ' + urli + ' is C URL.');
              }
          }
      }
    
    exampleUrlString = "https://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg\nhttps://cdn.domain.de/uploads/sites/4/2022/04/alpha1234567890z.jpg?resize=1024%2C600\nhttps://www.domainy.de/wp-content/uploads/150411_AB-43827__DSC1378.jpg\nhttps://www.domainB.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/channelB-881123-maxm-20220805-696x464.jpg\nhttps://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg\nhttps://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg";
    preprocessImgURL(exampleUrlString);
  ```

###### real output:

```
Row 0 is C URL.
Row 1 is A URL.
[no output as there is no else statement that could handle row 2]
Row 3 is B URL.
Row 4 is C URL. *
[no output as there is no else statement that could handle row 5]
```

##### WORKS (external loop, function processes only one url):

```js
function preprocessImgURL(url, imgrow) {
    const aRegex = /alpha\d{9,11}z/gi;
    const cRegex = /\d{6}_[a-zA-Z]{2,3}-\d{5,8}/gi;
    
    console.log(url);
    if(url.includes("channelB-") && (url.includes("domainB.de") || url.includes("domain-B.de"))) {
        console.log('Row ' + imgrow + ' is B Domain + B URL.');
    } else if(aRegex.test(url)) {
        console.log('Row ' + imgrow + ' is A URL.');
    } else if(cRegex.test(url)) {
        console.log('Row ' + imgrow + ' is C URL.');
    } else {
        console.log('Row ' + imgrow + ' doesnt match any criteria. (else statement reached)');
        console.log('Row ' + imgrow + ' matches b criteria: ' + ( url.includes("channelB-") && (url.includes("domainB.de") || url.includes("domain-B.de"))));
        console.log('Row ' + imgrow + ' matches aRegex: ' + aRegex.test(url));
        console.log('Row ' + imgrow + ' matches cRegex: ' + cRegex.test(url));
    }
        
}

urls = new Array(
    "https://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg", 
    "https://cdn.domain.de/uploads/sites/4/2022/04/alpha1234567890z.jpg?resize=1024%2C600", 
    "https://www.domainy.de/wp-content/uploads/150411_AB-43827__DSC1378.jpg", 
    "https://www.domainB.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/channelB-881123-maxm-20220805-696x464.jpg",
    "https://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg", "https://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg"
);

for (let urli = 0; urli < urls.length; urli++) {
    console.log('\n\nPROCESSING NEXT URL');
    preprocessImgURL(urls[urli], urli);
}
```

#### full html code to reproduce issue

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var imgrow = 0;
    function preprocessImgURL(url) {
        const urls = url.trim().split(/\r?\n/);
        const aRegex = /alpha\d{9,11}z/gi;
        const cRegex = /\d{6}_[a-zA-Z]{2,3}-\d{5,8}/gi;
        
        for (let urli = 0; urli < urls.length; urli++) {
            
            console.log(urls[urli]);
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += urls[urli] + '<br>';
            if(urls[urli].includes("channelB-") && (urls[urli].includes("domainB.de") || urls[urli].includes("domain-B.de"))) {
                console.log('Row ' + imgrow + ' is B Domain + B URL.');
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += 'Row ' + imgrow + ' is B Domain + B URL.' + '<br>';
            } else if(aRegex.test(urls[urli])) {
                console.log('Row ' + imgrow + ' is A URL.');
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += 'Row ' + imgrow + ' is A URL.' + '<br>';
            } else if(cRegex.test(urls[urli])) {
                console.log('Row ' + imgrow + ' is C URL.');
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += 'Row ' + imgrow + ' is C URL.' + '<br>';
            } else {
                console.log(cRegex);
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += cRegex + '<br>';
                console.log(cRegex.test(urls[urli]));
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += cRegex.test(urls[urli]) + '<br>';
            }
            
            console.log('NEXT URL');
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += '<br><br>';
            ++imgrow;
        }
    }
    </script>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4>example input</h4>
                    <p style="font-size: 80%;">
https://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg<br>
https://cdn.domain.de/uploads/sites/4/2022/04/alpha1234567890z.jpg?resize=1024%2C600<br>
https://www.domainy.de/wp-content/uploads/150411_AB-43827__DSC1378.jpg<br>
https://www.domainB.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/channelB-881123-maxm-20220805-696x464.jpg<br>
https://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg<br>
https://www.domain.de/wp-content/uploads/200115_AB-55789__DSC1235.jpg
                    </p>
                    <h4>relevant criteria (for now):</h4>
                        <p>A: not B && includes something like alpha[9-11digits]z <br>
                        B: includes channelB- && ( includes domainB.de || includes domain-B.de)<br>
                        C: not A && not B && includes something like [6digits]_[2-3letter]-[5-8digits]<br></p>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4>Image URLs (1 per row)</h4>
                    <textarea rows="5" name="imgurls" class="form-control" required onchange="preprocessImgURL(this.value)" style="font-size: 80%;"></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>
            
            <div  style="font-family: monospace;" id="result">
                <h4>Result:</h4>
            </div>
            
            <div style="font-family: monospace;">
                <h4>Expected/experienced Result for example input:</h4>
                <p>Row 0 is C URL. /  <br>
                Row 1 is A URL. /  <br>
                Row 2 is C URL. /  <br>
                Row 3 is B URL. /  <br>
                Row 4 is C URL. /  <br>
                Row 5 is C URL. /  <br></p>
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide what's the `input` for which `output` explicitly.

Comment: Lots of confusion. Elements not needed only adding noise are there and elements required are not listed in your question. The output doesn’t match the console.log statements and you made a strong statement in the title itself that it’s obviously false.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a snippet which can be used to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @LajosArpad & GodWin Thanks for your suggestions. I added a fully functional but hopefully lightweight enough code snippet to reproduce it really easy.

Comment: Please reduce your example to include only the specific data; this should be JS-only. It's *wildly* unlikely the same code with the same data would produce different results; it's almost certainly faulty assumptions. Is it *impossible*? Nope. But improbable.

Comment: @diegod Sorry for that. To be honest I didn't thought that the code details would be too important. It's an small script (well at least this part) and I think I must have made a conceptional mistake because. I just don't get it. I already tried playing around with the if-statements, the loop, the urls/input.

Comment: Thanks, Roberto! If you could reduce your snippet to contain 1. An array of URLs 2. A loop that processes the URLs and calls your function 3. An output that shows the result of the function vs. the expectation. Thanks!

Comment: Also, Lajos' request for a dedicated function to process a single URL will make it much easier to create automated tests at a later point.

Comment: It seems you fixed it by creating that function? (So maybe something to do with getting the lines from the text area? Any `<br>` in there for your first example?) Aside, I feel the function still has too many unrelated details (`imgrow` being one of them; just used for logging, should not be there). Make the function return a classification instead.

Comment: @Arjan Well it also doesn't work if I don't get the string from an HTML input but create it directly within JS. That's the reason for the headline btw. I think it must have something to do with the loop. -- OK I remove the imgrow variable. (Actually not for logging but a remnant of my original code. Used in case someone uses the input area more than ones to have a "global" row counting... however... not important for the sinppet.)

Comment: Ah, I missed there are multiple code snippets now, I only clicked the last. Well, the cleanest code works, problem solved. :-)

Comment: @Arjan But why?! :D Still want to understand why I cannot use the if-conditions inside a loop. :)

Comment: @Roberto, the first snippet tests for `if(urls[urli].includes("channelB-")) {` but in your working snippet you have `if(url.includes("channelB-") && (url.includes("domainB.de") || url.includes("domain-B.de"))) {`... maybe that is why you get different results?

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus Thanks for the idea. No, I just reduced the complexity there for the snippets to eliminate as much unrelated details as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the very same regular expression multiple times, like you're doing in the loop, [it may remember what it has processed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#using_test_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag):

> ### Using test() on a regex with the "global" flag
>
> When a regex has the [global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags_2) set, `test()` will advance the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) of the regex. ([`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) also advances the `lastIndex` property.)
>
> Further calls to `test(str)` will resume searching `str` starting from `lastIndex`. The `lastIndex` property will continue to increase each time `test()` returns `true`.
>
> Note: **As long as `test()` returns `true`, `lastIndex` will *not* reset—even when testing a different string!**
>
> When `test()` returns `false`, the calling regex's `lastIndex` property will reset to `0`.
>
> The following example demonstrates this behavior:
>
> ```js
> const regex = /foo/g; // the "global" flag is set
>
> // regex.lastIndex is at 0
> regex.test('foo')     // true
>
> // regex.lastIndex is now at 3
> regex.test('foo')     // false
>
> // regex.lastIndex is at 0
> regex.test('barfoo')  // true
>
> // regex.lastIndex is at 6
> regex.test('foobar')  // false
>
> // regex.lastIndex is at 0
> // (...and so on)
> ```

In your case, you do not need the global flag.

Comment: Thank you @arjan ! :) I knew I must have done a stupid mistake. (And also thanks to everyone else in the comments who tried to find the issue.)